# CSS Tabbed Selection not working in Chrome

Tags: html, css

I've noticed a very odd pattern of behavior for my CSS on one of my web pages.  I have 5 divs, which are shown / hidden based on if their corresponding 'tab' is clicked on a page.  The page name would be /example.aspx, but nothing displays unless I redirect them to /example.aspx#example-home.  Once they the #example-home div is displayed, the page works fine and users can select different tabs to show different divs.  The issue I've found, is that ONLY in chrome, when you refresh the page, everything is `display: none` even if the URL was still /example.aspx#example-home.  Does anyone have any ideas as to why this would happen only in chrome?

Relevant CSS:

```
#legends-wrapper
{
float:left;
width:953px;
padding:0px;
background-image:url(/images/offers/Legends/board-bg1.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position:top center;
position:relative;
left:-20px;
top:-10px;
}
div #legends-wrapper div:not(:target)
{
display:none;
}
div #legends-wrapper div:target
{
display:block;
}
ul.legends-nav
{
float:left;
width:938px;
height:35px;
margin-left:40px;
}

ul.legends-nav li
{
float:left;
display:inline;
list-style-type:none;
width:95px;
height:35px;
margin-left:72px;
}
.KER-copy
{
clear:both;
width:700px;
margin:auto;
font-size:xx-small;
text-align:left;
background-image:url(/images/Offers/Legends/KER-logo-mini.jpg);
background-position:top-left;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
padding-left:170px;
padding-top:15px;
padding-bottom:20px;
border-bottom:1px solid #5d554e;
margin-bottom:10px;
}
.KER-legal
{
clear:both;
font-size:xx-small;
}
```

Comment: Yes please post full code and maybe a jsfiddle for us to take a look at.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve by using JS to force the page to either the home div, or the div that they were currently viewing using location.hash.  I'm not sure what the underlying issue was but it appeared that chrome wasn't recognizing the hash on the URL when a user refreshed.

Javascript:

```
var hasHash = false;
var currentURL = location.href;
if(currentURL.indexOf('#') >= 0){
var hash = location.hash;
hasHash = true;
}
var newURL = "/example.aspx";
var home = "#example-home";
if(hasHash){
location.href = newURL.concat(hash);
}else{
location.href = newURL.concat(home);
}
```